# Count the number of rows returned from a view or stored procedure written in a table

Tags: function, stored-procedures, count, sql-server-2008-r2, rowcount

I need to created a SQL SERVER stored procedure which count for me the number or rows returned  from a view or a stored procedure writted in a table. For example this script:

```
select QueryString
From abo.PageContents 
where PageElementID = 1 and DataDomainID = 4
```

returns me:

```
select * from dbo.vGEcProduseAtrib
```

And a need to output the **number of rows returned** from the previous select (or `exec dbo.Example`) which come random, by the DataDomainID i selected. Thank you!

Comment: can you explain what you mean by `select QueryString...` returns me: `select * from dbo.vGEcProduseAtrib`. Is that the view definition?

Comment: The first select is from a config table where i have multiple views and stored procedures which are returned in different lists and reports in php view... The second select is written in QueryString column, is the result that came to me after executing the first select.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I need that for an report, to count the number of rows returned in a paginated list.